# Removing multiple block of lines of a text file in bash

Tags: bash, text, sed

Assume a text file with 40 lines of data. How can I remove lines 3 to 10, 13 to 20, 23 to 30, 33 to 40, in place using bash script?

I already know how to remove lines 3 to 10 with `sed`, but I wonder if there is a way to do all the removing, in place, with only one command line. I can use `for loop` but the problem is that with each iteration of loop the lines number will be changed and it needs some additional calculation of line numbers to be removed.

Comment: @Cyrus's answer is the way to go for this case, but for future reference, you can also add multiple commands to execute to a single `sed` invocation... `sed -e '3,10d' -e '14d' -e '22s/a/b/'`

Comment: @Kent's answer is definitely the way to go. It's simple, robust, extensible, etc.

Comment: Instead of saying you like to remove this and this, you could say `I would like to keep all lines like this 1,2 11,12 21,22 or like this, all lines where line number ends with 1 or 2 should be kept`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i '3,10d;13,20d;23,30d;33,40d' file
```

Comment: This can be constructed dynamically, if that's important: `for ((i=0; i<$(wc -l < file); i+=10)); do sed+="$((i+3)),$((i+10))d;"; done; sed -i "$sed" file`

Comment: For this small range also following would be possible: `sed -i 'N;p;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d' file`

Answer (score 5):

here is an awk oneliner, works for your needs no matter your file has 40 lines or 40k lines:

```
awk 'NR~/[12]$/' file
```

for example, with 50 lines:

```
kent$ seq 50|awk 'NR~/[12]$/'  
1
2
11
12
21
22
31
32
41
42
```

Comment: +1 I was going to go with `NR%10` but actually I prefer this.

Comment: @TomFenech `NR%10` needs "post-processing" like `NR%10 && NR%10<3`

Comment: Or `NR%10 ~ /[12]/` but it's unnecessary when you can just match the last digit as you've done.

Comment: @Kent You might explain what you are actually doing - namely "doing `awk`'s default action, which is to print the current line, if the line number ends in the digit `1` or `2`". Also, it's not strictly "in place" like the OP asked. You still get my +1 though :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanx for the vote, and thanx for the explanation too. There is in-place option for gawk 4.1.0. otherwise  `awk '...' file > foo && mv foo file`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '3~10,+7d' file
```

Deletes lines in the range of 3 and thereafter steps of 10 for the following 7 lines to be deleted.

If the file was longer than 40 lines and you were only interested in the first 40 lines:

```
sed '41,$b;3~10,+7d' file
```

The first instruction tells sed to ignore lines 41 to end-of-file.

Could also be written:

```
sed '1,40{3~10,+7d}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{m=NR%10} !(m==0 || m>=3)' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: You don't need to store the whole file. Do the filtering while you read the file: `awk '{m=NR%10} !(m==0 || m>3)'`

Comment: Yes, not sure why I wrote it that way.  I also misread that the OP wanted the lines removed, not printed.  Post updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Kent's answer is the way to go for this particular case, but in general:

```
$ seq 50 | awk '{idx=(NR%10)} idx>=1 && idx<=2'
1
2
11
12
21
22
31
32
41
```

The above will work even if you want to select the 4th through 7th lines out of every 13, for example:

```
$ seq 50 | awk '{idx=(NR%13)} idx>=4 && idx<=7'
4
5
6
7
17
18
19
20
30
31
32
33
43
44
45
46
```

its not constrained to N out of 10.

Or to select just the 3rd, 5th and 6th lines out of every 13:

```
$ seq 50 | awk 'BEGIN{split("3 5 6",tmp); for (i in tmp) tgt[tmp[i]]=1} tgt[NR%13]'
3
5
6
16
18
19
29
31
32
42
44
45
```

The point is - selecting ranges of lines is a job for awk, definitely not sed.